# expenditure minimization problem

Tags: calculus

I'm solving this problem:
$$\min_{x} p\cdot x \ \ \ \ \ s.t \ \ \ \Pi_{j=1}^{L}x_{j}^{\alpha_j} \geq u $$
Given, $u$, $\ p>>0$,  $\ \sum_{j=1}^{L}\alpha_j =1$ and $\alpha_j>0$

My solution is $x_j(p,u)=u\cdot \Pi_{i=1}^{L}(\frac{p_i}{\alpha_i})^{\alpha_{i}} $

Is this solution right? how can I check that?

Comment: Do you know the method of lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that at optimality, the constraint must be an equality, as otherwise we can reduce some $x_j$ to further reduce the objective.  So consider the equivalent problem:

Minimise $ \sum p_j x_j$ s.t. $ \prod x_j^{\alpha_j} = u$.  We have by the weighted AM-GM,
$$\sum p_j x_j = \sum \alpha_j \frac{p_j x_j}{\alpha_j} \ge \prod \left(\frac{p_j x_j}{\alpha_j}\right)^{\alpha_j} = u \prod \left(\frac{p_j}{\alpha_j}\right)^{\alpha_j}$$

where equality is obtained iff $p_i x_i = p_j x_j$ for every $i, j$.  So at the equality (which yields the optimum), we have
$$L\, p_j x_j = u \prod \left(\frac{p_j}{\alpha_j}\right)^{\alpha_j} \implies x_j = \frac{u}{ p_j \, L} \prod \left(\frac{p_j}{\alpha_j}\right)^{\alpha_j}$$

So you need to recheck your work...